# Chart js nested pie label colors in legend

Tags: chart.js, pie-chart

I'm trying to have 2 pie charts and show in the legend only the inner labels.
The issues is that seems the labels color (in the legend) are taken from the the outer dataset, probably because it is the first.

How can I change it?

```js
  var ctx = $("#myChart");
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
      labels: ['InnerLabel1','InnerLabebl2','InnerLabel3'],
      datasets: [{
        data: [1, 2, 1, 4],
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(31,119,180,0.5)','rgba(255,127,14,0.5)','rgba(255,127,14,0.5)','rgba(44,160,44,0.5)'
        ],
        labels: [
          'OuterLabel1','OuterLabel2','OuterLabel3','OuterLabel4'
        ]
      }, {
        data: [1, 3, 4],
        backgroundColor: [
          '#1f77b4','#ff7f0e','#2ca02c'
        ],
        labels: ['InnerLabel1','InnerLabebl2','InnerLabel3'],
      }, ]
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      legend: {
        display: true,
      },
      tooltips: {
        callbacks: {
            label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
            var dataset = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
            var index = tooltipItem.index;
            return dataset.labels[index] + ': ' + dataset.data[index];
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to generate the legend labels yourself by defining a [`legend.labels.generateLabels`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#legend-label-configuration) function together with a [`legend.onClick`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#configuration-options) that takes care of hiding and showing individual pie slices.

Here's an attempt of how this could be done.

```js
const innerDataset = {
  data: [1, 3, 4],
  backgroundColor: ['#1f77b4', '#ff7f0e', '#2ca02c'],
  labels: ['InnerLabel1', 'InnerLabebl2', 'InnerLabel3'],
};

var myChart = new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
        data: [1, 2, 1, 4],
        backgroundColor: ['rgba(31,119,180,0.5)', 'rgba(255,127,14,0.5)', 'rgba(255,127,14,0.5)', 'rgba(44,160,44,0.5)'],
        labels: ['OuterLabel1', 'OuterLabel2', 'OuterLabel3', 'OuterLabel4']
      },
      innerDataset
    ]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
      display: true,
    },
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          var dataset = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
          var index = tooltipItem.index;
          return dataset.labels[index] + ': ' + dataset.data[index];
        }
      }
    },
    legend: {
      labels: {
        generateLabels: () => innerDataset.labels.map((label, i) => ({
          text: label,
          fillStyle: innerDataset.backgroundColor[i],
          strokeStyle: '#fff',
          hidden: myChart ? myChart.getDatasetMeta(1).data[i].hidden : false
        }))
      },
      onClick: (event, legendItem) => {        
        const metaData = myChart.getDatasetMeta(1).data;
        const iData = innerDataset.labels.indexOf(legendItem.text);
        metaData[iData].hidden = !metaData[iData].hidden;
        myChart.update();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: @Liron C: meanwhile I found a solution on how to show legend labels of hidden slices with strike-through text. I updated the code in my answer  accoringly.